Beamer and sans-serif fonts through Helvetica, how to make \sf, \textsf, \mathsf to look the same?
I am working on a beamer document, where I would like Computer Modern serif fonts for all serif items, but would like Helvetica for any sans-serif items.

Here's what I currently get with the following MWE:
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{helvet}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Examples:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Usual text
\item Without modification: $f_{\sf test}(x) = x$
\item With explicit modification: $f_{\textsf{test}}(x) = x$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

I'd like it to be that the line which I have entered as $f_{\sf test}(x) = x$ to look like the one that I entered as $f_{\textsf{test}}(x) = x$. Is there any way to do that? I'd ideally also like the same output with $f_{\mathsf{test}}(x) =x$, that way whenever I'm in math mode, I can just know that I'll get my desired sans-serif font (Helvetica) whilst keeping the serif font as Computer Modern.

\sf is incorrect markup in latex and is no longer defined by the kernel. classes may choose to define it or not and may or may not define it to work in the way it works in plain.so I'd imagine saying \let\sf\sffamily at the end of your preamble (or, possibly, the start of the document, but hopefully not) ought to ensure (\sf x} is equivalent to \textsf{x}. but you really should rather write {\sffamily x}.
